# Finding example of base of subspace intersection subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to find base of

$span\{(1,0,1), (2,1,0)\} \ \ \cap \ \ \ \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x-y+z=0 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3} $

What I've done is:

1. Found the subspace/base of the $x-y+z=0$. That is vectors e.g. $(0,1,1), (-1,0,1), (2, -1, -1)$. Checked that they are linearly independent:
   $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1\\-1 & 0 & 1\\ 2 & -1 & -1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ so I guess that is the base (and subspace that they span?)?
2. For the intersection of these two, that is $span\{(1,0,1), (2,1,0)\} \ \cap \ span\{(0,1,0), (0,0,1), (1,0,0) \} $, I need to find vectors that satisfy equation $a \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix}2 \\1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = c\begin{bmatrix}0 \\1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + d \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + e \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ ? If so, I did: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \end{bmatrix} = 0 $$

And I got:

$$ b=c \\
a=d \\
a+2b-e=0 $$

Now what do I do with that? Find 3 linearly independent vectors that satisfy these equations?
Like $(2, 1, 1, 2, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0, 2)$ ? Or maye I should find 3 vectors that are in 3d pane and so the c and d parameters are not neccessary and only $(2, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2)$ would be enough?

I'm trying to learn math on my own, so I don't have anyone that could tell me, whether what I'm doing is correct or complete nonsense. If something that I wrote is complete nonsense, please tell me. If everything is correct, you could try to explain this to me why is it correct, what are the theoretical basis of it etc. I kind of did it with a help of chatGPT and google, so even if it is correct, it's not guaranteed that I actually get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found the subspace/base of the $x-y+z=0$. That is vectors e.g. $(0,1,1), (-1,0,1), (2, -1, -1)$. Checked that they are linearly independent:
> $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1\\-1 & 0 & 1\\ 2 & -1 & -1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ so I guess that is the base (and subspace that they span?)?

A couple of things here. First, and least importantly, those two matrices are not equal! They are row equivalent, i.e. a series of elementary row operations will transform one matrix into another, but the matrices are not the same, and thus not equal.

Secondly, and more importantly, while the three vectors are indeed linearly independent, the third vector, $(2, -1, -1)$ does not belong to the plane $x - y + z = 0$ (and you should absolutely substitute it into the equation to see that it is not satisfied).

In fact, you will find that no set of three vectors taken from the plane will be linearly independent. The space is two-dimensional, and any two linearly independent vectors (e.g. $(0, 1, 1)$ and $(-1, 0, 1)$) will span the subspace. But, if finding a basis is your goal, you shouldn't take my word for it. Try proving that any vector $(x, y, z)$ satisfying $x - y + z = 0$ is a linear combination of the two vectors (hint: the vector can be written as $(x, y, y - x)$, given $z = y - x$).

(Note: Below, I made an error, writing $(0, 2, 1)$ instead of $(2, 1, 0)$. I'm leaving the answer as is, and leaving the true answer as an exercise.)

Now, with that all said, I don't think that finding a basis for the second subspace is an all that helpful step. To find the intersection between the two spaces, you need to find all $(x, y, z)$ in $\operatorname{span}\{(1, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1)\}$ that also satisfies $x - y + z = 0$. Being in the span, we know that there exist scalars $a$ and $b$ such that
$$(x, y, z) = a(1, 0, 1) + b(0, 2, 1) = (a, 2b, a + b),$$
or as a system of linear equations,
$$\left\{\begin{aligned} x &= a \\ y &= 2b \\ z &= a + b\end{aligned} \right.$$
We also need $x - y + z = 0$, so this implies
$$a - 2b + a + b = 0,$$
hence $2a - b = 0$, and so $b = 2a$. This tells us that
$$(x, y, z) = a(1, 0, 1) + b(0, 2, 1) = a(1, 0, 1) + 2a(0, 2, 1) = a(1, 4, 3).$$
Vectors that lie in the intersection must take that form, and it's not difficult to see that vectors in that form belong to both subspaces. Thus, the vectors of this form will be the intersection.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the 2 vectors on the left are $(1,0,1), (2,1,0)$, so it should be $a(1,0,1)+b(2,1,0)=(a+2b, b, a)$, right?

Comment: @Pik Indeed, that was my mistake. I'm going to leave the answer roughly as is, and let you do the steps to find the true answer.